# Call function in javascript file from html onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-apps-script

This has been driving me crazy- I can't figure out why it wont work!

I have two files: myPage.html and myCode.gs in google scripts. I have deployed the html file as a web app, and I want the onclick event for the submit button to trigger the emailTech function from the myCode.gs file but it won't work! When I run the function straight from the file, it works fine.

I've done a few hours of research and tried to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="myCode.gs"></script>` but that causes an error when I refresh the web app. I have tried calling the function in the onClick event as `onClick= "google.script.run.emailTech()"` and `onClick= "emailTech()"` but neither work. I have also tried loading the emailTech function into the script tag in the header, but that didn't work either! What am I missing? Please help!

myPage.html file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
    <input type="submit" onclick="emailTech();" value="Submit" />
    </body>
```

myCode.gs file:

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage');
}

function emailTech(){

  Logger.log("is this firing?");
  var message = "This is the email message";
  MailApp.sendEmail("XYZ@abc.com", "This is the subject", message );

}
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: I'm not familiar with google apps (scripts), but however you would call the function in JavaScript normally, that should work in the onclick. If I were running into this problem, I would use the Inspector in chrome to explore the DOM and find out where my definitions were. The Inspector has a JS console you can use to execute JS on the fly.

Comment: when I put `<script type="text/javascript" src="myCode.gs">' it I get this error: Invalid script or HTML content: http://script.google.com/myCode.gs:1+1 - 2: Unexpected token < HtmlOutput:31+38 - 44: attribute type cannot have value date.

Comment: take a look at the example on [google apps developer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) in the part Success and Failure Handlers. It shows a example to deal with `onclick` events.  `<input type='button' value='Never Clicked'
 onclick='google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateButton).withUserObject(this).getCurrentDate()'>` I believe you cant call a Gs script like you would do with a JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: New answer - use `google.script.run`.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="google.script.run.emailTech();" value="Submit" />
</body>
```

Comment: That won't do what he wants.  (it will call it when building the HTML string)

Comment: @SLaks - right! Although it DID cause `emailTech()` to execute, it did so at the wrong time. Fixed it, with hint from Jacobvdb.

Comment: Yes it worked! I'm not sure if it was because I changed it back to "goole.script.run.emailTech();" or because I needed the capital C in the onClick, or because I changed it from "submit" to "button", but one of those things did the magic trick! Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: The key was `google.script.run.<function>`. The capitalization of html tags is irrelevant - you could use `onCLIck` if you want. See [html button v.s. html submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979363/html-button-v-s-html-submit) for a discussion of which to use when - Corey was right, button is most appropriate here. If you change to have a form, then use `submit`.

Answer (score 2):

You were actually on track with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="emailTech();" value="Submit" />
</body>
```

Don't use a `submit`; use a `button`. The semantics of submits and onclick handlers are a little bizarre (not just because of HtmlService sandboxing, but even in general) and don't play well with google.script.run. This is documented in the HtmlService user guide:

" You cannot use this technique with a regular submit button"