# What's the difference between submit and button?

Tags: javascript, html

This can be a real basic question but what is the difference between `<input type = "submit">` and `<button onclick="">Example</button>`?

It can't be done with `function` method in Javascript to achieve the same thing that the `submit` type button will? I always used `<button></button>` but I'd like to learn the difference.

Comment: Cannot mark it as duplicate but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-butto are the first two hits alone on this platform.

Comment: Take a look at [Difference between <input type='submit' /> and <button type='submit'>text</button>][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-butto

Thats what you want to know.

Comment: Have you performed a search on stackoverflow? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979363/html-button-v-s-html-submit), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)...

Comment: A quick search of google and stackoverflow will explain it http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?135004-Difference-between-input-type-quot-button-quot-and-quot-submit-quot

Comment: When I entered the question, the auto-complete didn't suggest anything like it so I didn't search but yes now I see, it has been asked plenty times. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a submit input will be the display label.

```
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="bar"> <!-- Displays [bar] -->
```

The child nodes of a submit button will be the display label. The value can be different and the label can include elements as well as text.

```
<button type="submit" name="foo" value="bar">
    <img src="arrow.png" alt=""> Baz
</button>
<!-- Displays [→ Baz] -->
```

---

There are no differences between them that are JavaScript related. You can't use JavaScript to couple or decouple the display label and submitted value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't noticed that this question was asked several times, though.

Comment: Pity is, I think this answer is more informative than the one on the original question