# button(submit) didn't work - but input(submit) work

Tags: php, html

I want to make Login page with PHP.

And want to use **button** but it didn't works.
and it looks like just refresh the page.

I tried button tag in the form.
How can I make this works??

```
<?php
  include "login.php";
?>

<form method="post" id="sign">

  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" name="user_mail" id="user_mail" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['user_mail'] ?? '') ?>">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="user_mail">Email</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" name="passcode" id="passcode" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['passcode'] ?? '') ?>">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="passcode">Password</label>
  </div>
</form>

//this <input> works
<input type="submit" name="signup" form="sign"/>
//I want to use this <button>
<button type="submit" name"signup" form "sign" formmethod="post"></button>

<?php
  if ($error ?? '') {

    echo addslashes($error);

  }
```

**login.php**

```
if ($_POST['signup'] ?? '') {

  $error = '';

  if (!$_POST['user_mail']) $error .= "<br />Please enter email";
  else if (!filter_var($_POST['user_mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error .= "<br />Please enter valid email";

  if (!$_POST['passcode']) $error .= "<br />Please enter password";
  else {

    if (strlen($_POST['passcode']) < 8) $error .= "<br />Please enter a password more than eight";
    if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST['passcode'])) $error .= "<br />please least one capital letter";

  }

  if ($error) $error = "there were errors:" . $error;
```

Comment: Your `<button>` needs to be inside the `<form>`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979363/html-button-v-s-html-submit

Comment: There is a typo. Check the `form "sign"`. It should be `form="sign"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<button>` means put a button on the page and execute whatever is in the `onclick` method.  `<submit>` submits a form.

If you want a button to sumbit your form, use the `onclick` method of the button to do it.  Why can't you use submit, though?

See here, they use a link `<a onclick='...'` but you can do the same for your button:  [How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link)

As @Arun says below, you can use:

`<button type='submit'>` inside your form, too.  There are lots of ways to do things, so my only advice on top of this is to be consistent.  I use `input` out of habit, and that way I don't have a bunch of mixed conventions throughout my code.

Comment: <button type="submit"> is same as of <input type="submit"> in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a form on button click, add click event of button using jquery and submit a form like:

Html:

```
<button type="submit" name"signup" id="btn_submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function() {
    $("#sign").submit(); // submit a form
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a action on the form element:

```
<form method="post" id="sign" action="login.php">
```

i don't know PHP so i might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 changes:

1. Add `action` attribute
2. Move your `button` element inside the form. You can't expect any button on the page to submit your form. It must be inside the form, to which it is associated.

```
<form method="post" id="sign" action="form-destination.php">

<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" name="user_mail" id="user_mail" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['user_mail'] ?? '') ?>">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="user_mail">Email</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" name="passcode" id="passcode" value="<?php echo addslashes($_POST['passcode'] ?? '') ?>">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="passcode">Password</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name"signup" form "sign" formmethod="post"></button>
</form>



<?php
  if ($error ?? '') {

    echo addslashes($error);

  }
?>
```