# saving data using button doesn't functioning

Tags: php, mysql

i have button under form method="POST"

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn3 btn-default">Publish</button>
<button  type="button" name="saved" class="btn3 btn-black">Save</button>
```

and i have this script running.. the submit button works perfectly fine but the saved button i dont know why but it doesn't functioning..here's the code.

```
$database = new Database();
            $conn= $database->getConnection();
            $db= new articles($conn);

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $id = $session_id;  
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $body = $_POST['artmsg'];
            $file = $_FILES['title_image'];

            $ress = $db->pubArticle($id,$title,$body,$datetoday);

              if($res) {
                $path = $db->uploadmyImg($file);
                $db->savemyImage($ress, $path);
              }

            ?> 
              <script>
               window.location = '../views/articles.php';
              </script> 
            <?php
              }if(isset($_POST['saved'])){
                $id = $session_id;
                $title = $_POST['title'];
                    $body = $_POST['artmsg'];
                    $file = $_FILES['title_image'];

                    $insrt = $db->articledraft($id,$title,$body);
                                if($res) {
                $path = $db->uploadmyImg($file);
                $db->savedimage($ress, $path);
                }
              ?>
              <script>
               window.location = '../views/articles.php';
              </script> 
              <?php 
              }
          ?>
```

help me please i just dont know why the other button doesn't functioning..

Comment: Take a look at `button` vs `submit`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979392/715105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn3 btn-default">Publish</button>

<button  type="submit" name="saved" class="btn3 btn-black">Save</button>
```

It should work fine

Comment: what is the difference between the two button type?.. any idea?.

Comment: There is 3 types of button in html documentation
1. button -> it is clickable button, you need to use onclick function to make any function for this
2. reset -> this type is for resetting form data
3. submit -> this type is for submit form data
please visit  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

```
<button  type="submit" name="saved" class="btn3 btn-black">Save</button>
```

Comment: i just wanted to ask what's the difference between the two button type?.

Comment: `type="button"` is just a button, no other functions, while `type="submit"` sends the form it belongs to.